# Stuck in Bootloader

Tags: root-access, bootloader

I have a rooted Pixel 2 XL that I was upgrading the OS on and when I attempted to do a sideload for TWRP, it got all messed up. Now it won't go past the bootloader and keeps randomly rebooting while on the bootloader. It appears to not read fully via USB, as it either shows the SN or ??????????? when I do fastboot devices. I've tried reloading a new bootloader to no avail. I'm also unsuccessful at flashing a new OS. Hoping someone can help.

Comment: do everything you can to get fastboot working! use official [tools](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip) and [drivers](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/usb_driver_r13-windows.zip). try different usb-cables, computers with windows/linux. unzip [stock ROM](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/taimen-rp1a.201005.004-factory-f797c86c.zip) run *'fastboot flashing unlock_critical'* and '*flash-all.bat*' **Do NOT re-lock bootloader**